# mysql_pconnect() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, mysql, database

How I connect to the mysq_pconnect?

I have this config:

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'sampleuser');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'samplepassword');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'sampledatabase');
    $conn=mysql_pconnect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die ("Error connecting to " . DB_DATABASE);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die ("Error: Cannot access " . DB_DATABASE . " database");
?>
```

Do I have to fix anything to enable the mysql_pconnect()?

Comment: Why do you need it in the first place? Will a `mysql_connect()` not do?

Comment: Why do you need it in the first place? You should be using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you coding this way ? take a look at [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal) , now to the point of your question: Some crappy hosts disable this function because lazy programmers often make a mess with persistent connections, leaving them open ad infinitum causing database server errors.

Comment: so I could just call it whenever I need it using this //Include database connection details
 require_once("config.html");
 require("clean.php");

Comment: I'd argue that it's the _crappy_ hosts that leave it enabled :) On a shared server, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need persistent connections. But the host should turn them off normally, not with disable-function.

The host has got it wrong, conplain!